# An error occurred while creating an application on firebase@9.0.0-beta.2 + NUXT

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I create an application with firebase@9.0.0-beta.2
I get the error

Created a folder `plugins` add file `firebase.js`

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  databaseURL: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: '',
  appId: ''
}
let firebaseApp
try {
  firebaseApp = getApp()
} catch (e) {
  firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp, {})
export { db }
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
...
plugins: [    
    '~/plugins/firebase.js'
  ],
...
```

I get the error:

`error  'getApp' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: Does this one work locally? The error states that you don't have `getApp`and it is indeed not to be seen anywhere in the snippet that you have shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getApp()` is not a built-in method and must be called from the appropriate library, in this case: `FirebaseApp.getApp()`

```
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
getApps().length === 0 ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();
```

**OR**

```
if (FirebaseApp.getApps(context).isEmpty()) {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);
}
```

Comment: This option worked  `import { initializeApp, getApp } from 'firebase/app'`